# Converting shapefiles (SHP) to KML

Tags: shapefile, convert, kml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Converting between KML and shapefile (SHP) format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-convert-kml-to-esris-shapefile-format)

I have SHP files, I want KML files, what tools can convert?

Comment: Asked and answered - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-convert-kml-to-esris-shapefile-format