# KML (KMZ) to layer including all attributes

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, mapinfo, kmz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes)

This question is here in many variations but though I went through it I still don't have any good solution how to import KMZ/KML to GIS software - no matter if QGIS, ArcGIS, Mapinfo... All these softwares can now (5th 11/2012) more or less open/import KMZ/KML but none of them can do it including attributes (at least not with kml/kmz mentioned below).

I have also tried to use "Zonum Kml2shp", ogr2ogr (not sure what "*The LIBKML driver with ExtendedData handling is now incorporated in GDAL Version 1.9.2 onwards, OSGEO4W packages, MS4W and Qgis Master.*" means because I have installed the new version of OSGEO4W and still can't get attributes)

The data I need to convert are from Queensland Government Wetland Map:
http://wetlandinfo.derm.qld.gov.au/wetlands/MappingFandD/WetlandMapsAndData/KMLMaps.html

Also in the image:

[image: KML file with attributes]

KML example of polygon:

```
<Placemark>
                    <name>Sys -17.59027,143.15424</name>
                    <styleUrl>#R_WB</styleUrl>
                    <ExtendedData>
                        <Data><displayName>System</displayName><value>Riverine</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Wetland RE</displayName><value>2.3.24x11</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Wetland RE Percent</displayName><value>100</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Subdominant Wetland</displayName><value>-</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Legend</displayName><value>R_WB</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Hydrological Modifier</displayName><value>No modifications observed</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Salinity</displayName><value>Fresh</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Floodplain</displayName><value>-</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Regime</displayName><value>Commonly (80-100% of images)</value></Data>
                        <Data><displayName>Habitat</displayName><value>Riverine</value></Data>
                    </ExtendedData>
                    <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                            <LinearRing>
                                <coordinates>143.16006,-17.58812 143.16081,-17.58859 143.1611,-17.58858 143.16222,-17.58841 143.16225,-17.58889 143.16159,-17.58914 143.16083,-17.58917 143.1606,-17.58923 143.15935,-17.58917 143.15884,-17.58908 143.15818,-17.58907 143.15783,-17.5891 143.15765,-17.58914 143.15662,-17.58958 143.15621,-17.58979 143.15532,-17.59033 143.15496,-17.59042 143.15466,-17.59036 143.15457,-17.59036 143.15446,-17.5904 143.15416,-17.59064 143.15401,-17.59088 143.15396,-17.59092 143.15306,-17.5914 143.15261,-17.59179 143.15179,-17.59219 143.15139,-17.59222 143.151,-17.59218 143.15091,-17.59218 143.15091,-17.59241 143.14997,-17.59242 143.14997,-17.59219 143.15008,-17.59219 143.14991,-17.59195 143.14966,-17.59182 143.14966,-17.59169 143.1499,-17.59148 143.1499,-17.5914 143.14968,-17.59117 143.15021,-17.59111 143.15099,-17.59095 143.15176,-17.59064 143.15233,-17.59051 143.15328,-17.59019 143.15342,-17.59016 143.1541,-17.59015 143.15515,-17.58977 143.15652,-17.58912 143.15712,-17.58888 143.15732,-17.58883 143.15759,-17.58879 143.15793,-17.58876 143.15879,-17.58852 143.16006,-17.58812 </coordinates>
                            </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                    </Polygon>
                </Placemark>
```

But there are many other data in KML/KMZ I would like to use with the same problem - no attributes after conversion = useless. Is it really that hard to get attributes from KML/KMZ? I don't see any limitation why this file couldn't be converted for example to one Mapinfo TAB file including points/polygons/lines, attributes in table ("ExtendedData") to it and at the end as bonus also colors for lines and polygons :)

So sorry for repeating this question again, but is here actually any way to import KML (KMZ) to layer (Mapinfo TAB / ESRI shapefile / Any easily importable GIS format) including all attributes "ExtendedData"?