# KML file saved from KMZ missing tabular data

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, kmz

I saved a KML file in Google Earth from this KMZ ... https://www.rampp-team.com/documents/pennsylvania/watershed/LowerSusquehanna/lancaster_pa/Lancaster_CSLF.zip . Upon opening the KML file in QGIS, all of the tabular data is the same for all of the polygons, even though when the KMZ was loaded into Google Earth, there was color coding based on, apparently, tabular data.

Is there any way to preserve the data so that I can work with it in ArcView (shapefiles)?

There seems to be missing information in the KML that is present when displayed in Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the kml file, I see color information inside the `<description>` tag.

The kml driver of QGIS puts that information in a column named `description`, but can not use the information to colour the objects.

It might be that Google Earth can handle that data, but QGIS can not (and Arcview presumably neither).

This question gives some hints how kml extra data can be read:

[How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes)

but it seems that your data is not following the kml specification.