# Preventing QGIS from losing information in attribute table during KML to SHP conversion?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, attribute-table

I have a Shapefile with certain information in the attribute table. I convert it with QGIS 2.14 to KML. I convert the KML back to SHP. When I open the attribute table, all the infromation is lost. How can I prevent QGIS doing this?

Comment: Strange. It preserves the attribute table for me. Is there some intermediary step you're performing in between the two conversions?

Comment: maybe you see a connection [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110015/13507)

Comment: Do you know if your attributes are in the KML's Extended Data, or only in the HTML in the balloon descriptions?  If the attributes in your KML file are actually separated out as name/value pairs in the ExtendedData section of each KML feature, then most KML to SHP tools should be able to extract the attributes out to an attribute table. But if the attributes are only included as part of the HTML blobs in each KML feature's description tag, then you're out of luck... you'll need to parse through the HTML of each balloon to extract the features.