# KML to shapefile will not convert attributes embedded in the description field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, kml, google-earth

I have a point shapefile on which I used the "Layer to KML" tool on ArcMap. This tool successfully converted the shapefile into a KML containing all the attributes embedded in the "Placemark Description" field in Google Earth which serves my purposes. However when I try to go the opposite direction, namely from KML back to layer or shapefile using "KML to Layer" tool in ArcMap, all the attributes are lost and I cannot see them in the resulting Shapefile.

Is there any way to somehow expose these embedded attributes?

Or maybe export the shapefile such that the attributes are not embedded in the description in the first place?

I have third parties who need to edit my shapefiles in Google Earth and send them back to me to convert back to shapefiles. The back and forth from Arc to GE is quite paramount to my situation.

Comment: It's probably worth reviewing some of the [most frequently asked questions about KML here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kml?sort=frequent).

Comment: try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes-using-qgis