# Converting KML to TAB while maintaining the path to and name of embedded image

Tags: qgis, kml, mapinfo, global-mapper, mappt

I have a number of kml files that have images linked in them. When I try to convert them to tab using FME/UniversalTranslator/QGIS/GlobalMapper I get a tab file which has the spatial location of the points but the attribute table does not include the name of the image. How can I get this? a process entirely in Mapinfo 12 will be ideal.

```
"<description>&lt;img src=&quot;MAPPT_20151210_110739_-1565318452.jpg&quot; width=&quot;480px&quot;/&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;MAPPT_20151210_110739_-1565318452.jpg&quot;&gt;To view original size of image file click RIGHT BUTTON and choose OPEN LINK.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;table border=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Type&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Tent&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Comments&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Maintenance Action&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;No action&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Post Material&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Steel&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Sign Material&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Aluminium&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Sign Condition&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Good&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Post Installation&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;One post sign&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;User&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;John Kenna&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Logo&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;None&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Post Condition&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Good&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Date/Time&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;10-12-2015 11:08&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</description>
```

So I need MAPPT_20151210_110739_-1565318452.jpg to be put in the "Image" attribute of the generated table along with all the other data in their own attributes.

I have seen similar questions here re: getting the extended data but none of them deal with getting the image name.

I have tried Global Mapper (my go to for this kind of work), QGIS, KML2SHP and FME. QGIS doesn't even separate the extended data (as per comments in [How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes-using-qgis)). The others do this but don't give me the image name.

The only "complex" solution I can think of is to convert to tab in GM Script and then read the kml in python and extract the value between [img src="] and [;] and put this into the tab as value for the image attribute. Surely there's a better solution!

Here a sample dataset -it has the kml, kmz and a shp plus the images. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjBqNsSHofKQkRhWGtPamJTcmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using FME Quick Translator that comes with MapInfo Pro you need to make sure that you specify FME to include this Schema Attribute: kml_description.

This column will afterwards contain the entire string for the image, like:

```
<img src="MAPPT_20151210_110201_614270222.jpg" width="480px"/></br></br><a href="MAPPT_20151210_110201_614270222.jpg">To view original size of image file click RIGHT BUTTON and choose OPEN LINK.</a></br></br><table border="1"><tr><td>Type</td><td>Village
```

You might need to "clean" that up a bit if you only want the image name.
You can use this update statement to extract the image name from the string:

```
Update Placemark 
   Set kml_description = Mid$(kml_description
        , (Instr(1, kml_description, "src=") + 5)
        , Instr((Instr(1, kml_description, "src=") + 5)
              , kml_description, ".jpg") - (Instr(1, kml_description
              , "src=") + 1)
        )
```

Comment: brilliant. The extraction works well. I tried the code in the update statement and it fails with syntax error.

Comment: Make sure the quotation marks are correct and also make it a single line statement in the MapBasic window just to avoid any misinterpretation. I'll check the syntax again but it should work unless I made an error when copying it from the MapBasic window.

Comment: Wonderful -works perfectly now. ## Update Placemark Set kml_description = Mid$(kml_description, (Instr(1, kml_description, "src=") + 5), Instr((Instr(1, kml_description, "src=") + 5), kml_description, ".jpg") - (Instr(1, kml_description, "src=") + 1)) ##