# Not all KML attributes import into attribute table

Tags: qgis, kml, import, vector-layer

I have a .KML file that has placemarks that have four main pieces of data that I want to use in QGIS.  When I do 'Add Vector Layer' and select my KML file it imports all the placemarks as feature points as expected. But when I right click on the layer and select 'Open attribute table only two of the attributes are there.

I need these four attributes in QGIS.

```
<name>9255 LECALDERWOOD LN</name>
<description>9255</description>
<address>9255 LECALDERWOOD LN, San Fransi, CA</address>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="Terminal Address"><value>r 9252 meridian av</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

Example Placemark:

```
<Placemark>
<name>9255 LECALDERWOOD LN</name>
<description>9255</description>
<address>9255 LECALDERWOOD LN, San Fransi, CA</address>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="Terminal Address"><value>r 5252 meridian av</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
<coordinates>-121.893896,37.249197,0</coordinates>
</Point>
<Style>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>https://www.qcdata.s3.amazonaws.com/img/earthit/house2.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
</Placemark>
```

Attribute table:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to get it to import all attributes?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes using QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes-using-qgis)