# Converting KML to shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kml

I am a beginner in QGIS

I am planning to add line events on a route at 200m intervals.

I have done georeferencing of the map and digitized file in Kml format.

Can i convert this file into a shapefile?

I collected the road details of a 15 km road stretch at 200m intervals.

I want to display and analyse the collected features of the road in  GIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Here you seem to be stuck converting a KML file to a shapefile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting KML to shapefile without losing attributes using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/converting-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes-using-qgis)