# Synchronizing KML file in Google Earth with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file in Google Earth that I keep updated.

Usually every update I save this KML file then I import it to ArcMap.

Is there any way to sync this KML file with ArcMap?

I saw this [Link](http://en.acolita.com/synchronize-arcgis-arcmap-10-with-google-earth.html) but it didn't work with ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop (i didn't find the file ESRIRegAsm.exe and I couldn't add it as plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Your link is totally irrelevant with your problem. Your link is about ArcBlueTile which is a library to add google,bing,... base maps to ArcGIS.

As far as I know you can neither edit nor synchronize Kml or kmz files with ArcGIS Desktop.

You should edit your kml with google earth and once you are done, import it to ArcGIS and do your stuff there (KML to Layer Tool).

See [How to Convert a KML File into an ArcGIS Compatible Format](http://www.gislounge.com/how-to-import-a-kml-file-into-arcgis/)

Once you are finished in ArcGIS, export your layer back to kml (kmz) and then import to Google Earth.

Another option is to use ogr2ogr to convert between kml and shapefiles. See
[How to convert between KML and Esri's shapefile (SHP) format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-convert-between-kml-and-esris-shapefile-shp-format)