# Simple script to batch-convert KML to SHP or G

Tags: shapefile, kml

I'm not sure if this is possible given the looseness of KML files, but I have a couple thousand KML files that I would like to convert to SHP files. They are almost exclusively line or point data. I believe it is mostly possible to convert kmls via a GUI functionality in QGIS or ArcGIS but I would hopefully be able to do them all at once via command line.

Comment: [Help sample #2 here in the doc](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-to-layer.htm) converts all KML files in a folder into a single GDB for ArcGIS.

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-convert-between-kml-and-esris-shapefile-shp-format

Comment: These are great. But does anyone know if this works when the initial kmls are in a nested file structure. Is it possible to run this script and maintain the same file structure with the kmls? I think I could figure out how to do this with a linux/Unix system but I am forced to use a windows platform for work for the GIS software for work and don't know how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is two options to do this that I can think of. One would be to write a very simple loop within model builder or Arcpy with Arcgis and use the KML to layer tool. Without the KML files I don't know what your results would look like. 
The other more comand line based option would be using GDAL. Your question is almost idential to [How to convert between KML and Esri's shapefile (SHP) format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-convert-between-kml-and-esris-shapefile-shp-format) I would recommend checking that out as this is probably a duplicate.