# Importing a shapefile to Google Earth Engine without Fusion Tables

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, convert, kml

I would like to import the Sentinel-2 tiling grid as an asset to Google Earth Engine. This grid is provided as a `.kml` file on [an ESA page](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products): [.kml-File](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/documents/247904/1955685/S2A_OPER_GIP_TILPAR_MPC__20151209T095117_V20150622T000000_21000101T000000_B00.kml)

Now, unfortunately, Google has discontinued Fusion Tables which formerly could be used to convert `.kml` files to FeatureCollections. A straight-forward solution seems to be the offline conversion of the `.kml` file to a `.shp` file and upload it then via Google Earth Engine's Asset functionality. Problem is: I cannot transform the `.kml` file! Drawing inspiration from [another thread on here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98/converting-between-kml-and-shapefile-shp-format), I tried `ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' S2-tiles.shp S2A_OPER_GIP_TILPAR_MPC__20151209T095117_V20150622T000000_21000101T000000_B00.kml`, but this just gives the following error message:

```
ERROR 6: Geometry type of `3D Geometry Collection' not supported in shapefiles.  
Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.                                                                                                                                  
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation of layer Features (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Long story short: Is there any (convenient?) way to import `.kml` files to Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add -nlt POLYGON to your command.

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' tiles.shp S2A_OPER_GIP_TILPAR_MPC__20151209T095117_V20150622T000000_21000101T000000_B00.kml -nlt POLYGON
```

Comment: That did the job, thank you very much!